# file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software

Tags: android, gradle, virus

I have a library that used some JavaScript files. But android studio recognize them as a Virus and stop building. For example It's an error for one of these files

> C:\Users\user\Documents\App\build\intermediates\assets\debug\load_files.js (Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software)

Is there any way to ignore this process for checking asset files? These files are not virus and i want compile them with my application

**Update :** It's not a Windows Defender's error. Everything is disabled. Also my antivirus has no problem with these files.

Comment: You should check the file in question with https://VirusTotal.com. As it belongs to Google you will see why you get this message. May be the message is correct and the JavaScript file has a security problem?

Comment: No ... There isn't any problem in VirusTotal. Is there any way to ignore this error? @Robert